# Netty ObjectDecoder throws java.io.StreamCorruptedException: unexpected end of block data - Revisited

Tags: netty

I raised this issue in January (thread [Netty ObjectDecoder throws java.io.StreamCorruptedException: unexpected end of block data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790649/netty-objectdecoder-throws-java-io-streamcorruptedexception-unexpected-end-of-b)) but got side-tracked and have recently come back to the problem.

Either ObjectDecoder breaks or I have an object that causes ObjectDecoder to break when running under Oracles Java 1.7.0_03. Dropping back to run on a 1.6.0_31 JVM and everything runs perfectly. I see this behaviour running Netty-3.2.7-Final which I was using and under Netty-3.3.1-Final.

Could someone let me know what and where I need to send to enable this to be investigated.

Regards

EDIT:

Sorry - I omitted some vital information.

ObjectDecoder breaks when the object is encoded under a 1.6 JVM and is decoded in a 1.7 JVM. 1.7 to 1.7 works as expected as does 1.7 to 1.6