# Netty ObjectEncoders/ObjectDecoders on android causing StreamCorruptedException

Tags: android, netty

I want to write a Client on android phone and send an Object to a Server running on my windows PC (using ObjectDecoderInputStream ), but had these Exception

Exception

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: unexpected end of block data
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.access$300(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$GetFieldImpl.readFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFields(Unknown Source)
at java.net.InetSocketAddress.readObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.serialization.ObjectDecoderInputStream.readObject(ObjectDecoderInputStream.java:115)
at MainActivity.main(MainActivity.java:30)
```

But when I use CompatibleObjectEncoder/Decoder on my phone and ObjectInputStream on my PC, it works fine. And if I change the android code to Java code, and run the client on my PC to send my self the Object using ObjectEncoder and its correlated InputStream, it works fine.

By the way, I use netty 3.6.3 final and my android device is 2.3.7 gingerbread (which uses jre 1.5 or 1.6), my PC is jre 1.7, could that be a problem?

Comment: Netty IO start using java 7 classes since 3.5.0, try downgrade netty to 3.4.x and see if that works.

Comment: I have tried 3.4.6, 3.4.2, 3.2.6 and none of them worked. I think its because android has its own environment which is not compatible with both java 6 and 7.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds similair to my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028894/netty-objectdecoder-throws-java-io-streamcorruptedexception-unexpected-end-of-b) - I never got to the bottom of it, but changing the JVM so both ends run the same version stopped the error

Comment: Thanks. It is true, but I need to run that on android and communicate with my PC, is there a way to let android compatible with jre 1.7?

Comment: You could test to see if it's the same problem by downgrading your PC to JVM version 6 to see if the problem goes away

Comment: I have tested and here is the conclusion. JVM 6 is not compatible with JVM 7, and android is not compatible with both JVM 6 and JVM 7